# Heroku undefined method error in ActionView

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Heroku logs shows the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `accepted_answer_id' for #<Question:0x000000052fd1e0>)
```

As background, I have a model `Question`, which `has_many` Answers.  `Question` also has a column `accepted_answer_id`.

The undefined method error is referring a line in `_question.html.erb`, where its used to customized the display of the answer count in a different shaded background

```
  <% if question.answers.count > 0 %> 

    <% if question.accepted_answer_id %>
        <div class="pickedanswer">
          <h4><%= question.answers.count %></h4>
        </div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="numanswer">
          <h4><%= question.answers.count %></h4>
        </div>
    <% end %>

  <% else %>

      <div class="noanswer">
        <h4><%= question.answers.count%></h4>
      </div>

  <% end %>
```

I think the error may be raised due to the fact that initially `question.accepted_answer_id` is `nil`.. but given the way I structured the logic I do not know why it couldn't simply follow along (as it has done successfully in development).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you push the DB schema to heroku (if you are using their db)?

Comment: I did run `heroku run rake db:migrate` which should have pushed up the schema.

Comment: `heroku run rake db:migrate` does not apply the schema, only runs pending migrations that it knows about. Can you run `heroku pg:psql -a app_name` and confirm that database table has that column with `\d questions` ?

Comment: I believe `heroku db:push` might work for you (although it will destroy everything inside the DB).

Comment: @ctshryock thanks for helping out again :)  great suggestion - when I ran `\d questions`, I did not see the column `accepted_answer_id`, although when I ran `bundle exec annotate` during development it listed that as one of the columns.  Is there a way to push up the schema? (I will try `db:push` now)

Comment: @ TheDude - unfortunately now I got "time zone displacement out of range" error.  Following the discussion [here](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/92), I hope I could downgrade to ruby 1.9.2 and try again.

Comment: Dang, I have limited experience with Heroku, but that usually did the trick for me when I ran into that issue. Hopefully you find a solution!

Comment: This is just a hunch, but in the view file where you render the partial, are you passing the local variable `question` some value? Are you doing something like `... :question => @question`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema is missing that attribute. If your code works locally, then either you added that column manually, or a migration is not in your version control.

You can see what migrations have run like so:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate:status --app app_name
```

This will show if any of your migrations haven't been ran. You should match those to your local migrations. Are you maybe missing one?

Running `db:push` will **destroy your remote database** and replace it with a local copy, at best. Generally you should use `pgbackups:restore` to do this kind of thing (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

Comment: Everything worked!  I'd also like to add that running `heroku restart` after running the `db:migrate` was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this problem multiple times and these are the steps I take:

1. First make sure you have migrated the database on heroku:

   ```
   heroku run rake db:migrate
   ```
2. Make sure the database was actually migrated on heroku:

   ```
   heroku pg:psql -a app_name
   \d table_name
   ```
3. Finally restart the app on heroku:

   ```
   heroku restart
   ```